# If statements in Excel with cells containing CJK characters

Tags: excel, cjk

I am trying to make an IF statement in Excel 2016. My spreadsheet has Japanese characters, and I need to make a comparison like

```
=IF(A2="ア", TRUE, FALSE)
```

However, the function always returns false, even when A2 actually contains katakana ア.

Comment: Cell A2 has Japanese characters? or character

Comment: Works fine in my copy of Excel. Check what language packs are installed in your Excel

Comment: @Karthick Ginasekaram The cell has only the character ア

Comment: @Tom I will check my language packs

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Japanese language pack like @[Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3042759/tom) mentioned, selected Japanese as the default editing language and it works fine. Thank you, Tom!